# Scrolling of UITableView is not smooth when updating attributedText of UITextView in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, scroll, uitextview

I have a `ViewController` that has a `UITableView`, and tableview has many cells with `UITextView`.

```
class FeatureCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var featureNameTextView: UITextView!
}

class ReviewViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let entity = tableViewData[indexPath.row]

        let cell: FeatureCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FeatureCell

        let featureNameAttributedString = "<p>Actual HTML String</p>".getAttributedTextOfHTMLString(WithParagraphStyle: nil, font: Theme.textStyle.sfProTextRegular, textColor: .darkGray)
        cell.featureNameTextView.attributedText = featureNameAttributedString
        return cell
    }
}
```

The featureNameAttributedString  is generated from the HTML string which is coming from the API. I have used below extension to generate the attributed string from the HTML.

```
    func getAttributedTextOfHTMLString(WithParagraphStyle paragraphStyle: NSMutableParagraphStyle?, font: UIFont?, textColor: UIColor?) -> NSMutableAttributedString? {
        guard let htmlData = NSString(string: self).data(using: String.Encoding.unicode.rawValue) else {
            return NSMutableAttributedString(string: self)
        }
        let options = [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html]
        guard let attributedString = try? NSMutableAttributedString(data: htmlData, options: options, documentAttributes: nil) else {
            return NSMutableAttributedString(string: self)
        }
        let finalAttributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: attributedString)
        let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedString.length)
        if let paragraph = paragraphStyle {
            finalAttributedText.addAttribute(.paragraphStyle, value: paragraph, range: range)
        }
        if let font = font {
            finalAttributedText.addAttribute(.font, value: font, range: range)
        }
        if let color = textColor {
            finalAttributedText.addAttribute(.foregroundColor, value: color, range: range)
        }
        return finalAttributedText
    }
}
```

If featureNameAttributedString’s length is too long and when cell is updating the attributedString, tableView'scrolling is laggy.

If the actual html string is contain with the sup tag and cell’s height is set dynamically as per the attributedString’s size, tableview is not scrolling smoothly.

[image]

Sécurité McAfeeMD - Mieux

If I set the simple string text instead of attributedText into textview, the scrolling is smooth.

Any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: How old is this code? cellForRowAt has changed to `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {`

Comment: As you said **The featureNameAttributedString is generated from the HTML string which is coming from the API.**, then instead of using `UITextView` why won't you use `UILabel`. Is there any specified reason of using `UITextView` ??